# How to solve this problem in JasperReport?

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to print a table in pdf document. I need to use two javabean datasource to populate the data in the table. So i used two subreport parallely to map the data.The problem what i am facing is i could not able to organize the second subreport content corresponding to first subreport.That is , if any field's width is big in the first subreport then content in the second report will not align properly corresponding to the first subreport.The below sample will give a good idea about the problem

**My expected Output**

```
       SubReport1                     SubReport2

  S.No     Value                  S.No       Value

   1      value from first         1          value from second bean
          java bean value 
          bean   

   2      value from first bean    2          value from second bean
```

**Result which i am getting**

```
      SubReport1                    SubReport2

   S.No     Value               S.No       Value

   1     value from first        1          value from second bean
         java bean value        2          value from second bean       
          bean   

   2      value from first bean
```

Please kindly help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: The question's title is not clear at all. Anyone care to help? (I don't have enough reputation.)

Answer (score 1):

As @Boris suggested first thing remove the subreports.

Since you are using `BeanDatasource` then you can put all the business and logic in your code and give the report a ready made list.

Make a new object, lets call it `ReportRow`, don't use that name of course :).

```
public class ReportRow{
    int sNumber1;
    int sNumber2:
    String value1:
    String value2:
    //setters and getters
}
```

Now create a new `ArrayList<ReportRow>` and pass at as the datasource.

HTH.

Comment: it seems that kumar doesn't have an access to the source which emits these two arrays

Answer (score 0):

Subreports are like function arguments. They are evaluated prior to calling the function and don't know about each other. There are two solutions for your problem:

1. remove both subreports and render
   data in the main report
2. append some
   nonprinting characters to the
   shorter of two values that are
   supposed to be rendered in the same
   row

Comment: Hi Boris thanks for your interest.Actually i am using JavaBeanDatasource and my bean returning two ArrayList.so to populate  this ArryList values i used Subreport .I hope we can't directly populate ArrayList inside mainreport directly.We cant use nonprinting char also because sometimes second subreport value may be big than the first one.Is there is anyother possiblity?.